# What good resources can you suggest to learn advanced WCF?

Tags: wcf

I'm looking for any beyond basic resources that can help me to be proficient with WCF.

I found [Microsoft Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/wcf-resources.aspx#training) that are pretty good but I'm looking for more.  I'd really appreciate if you point me to more resources.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a really good book my Michele Leroux Bustamante called [Learning WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101627) (something like a pre-cursor to Juwal Lowy's more advanced book). She goes into great detail on all topics of WCF, even some very advanced ones (like federated authentication).

Michele has also recorded a 15-part screencast series on MSDN called "WCF Top-to-Bottom" which is a really great way to get started into WCF programming. Check out her [link collection](http://www.dasblonde.net/WCFWebcastSeries.aspx) for that series.

Marc

Comment: Yes - recomended purchase! I've also found http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/ a useful resource.

Answer (score 1):

I like Juval Lowy's [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002AWX8UK).